# Django / better way to make follow model and get follower and following list

Tags: python, django

my code

views

```
class FollowView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        follow_from = request.user
        follow_to_username = request.POST.get('follow_to')
        follow_to = get_object_or_404(User, username=follow_to_username)
    
        try:
            follow_obj = Follow.objects.get(follow_from=follow_from, follow_to=follow_to)
            follow_obj.delete()
        except Follow.DoesNotExist:
            follow_obj = Follow.objects.create(follow_from=follow_from, follow_to=follow_to)

        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

model

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follow_from = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='following', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follow_to = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='follower', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.follow_from} follows {self.follow_to}"
```

template of user profile

```
<div class="card-body">
  <p> {{ object.user }} </p>
  <p> {{ object.state_message }}</p>

  <p> following </p>
  {% for follow in object.user.following.all %}
  <p> {{ follow.follow_to }}</p>
  {% endfor%}

  <br>

  <p> followers </p>
  {% for follow in object.user.follower.all %}
  <p> {{ follow.follow_from }}</p>
  {% endfor%}
</div>
```

when i try to get one user's followers and following users
{% for follow in object.user.following(or follower).all %}
like this
i have to use ".follow_to" or ".follow_from" once more
This way is a bit confusing to use.
What i want is get "one user's follower" and "one user's following" using just keyword 'followers', and 'following'.
Should i try different way of making follow model?
please give me advice or idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a custom user model you can add a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) with `'self'` and your model `Follow` as the through model, while keeping `symmetrical=False`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Follow', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers')
    ...
```

Now you can directly access the related models by `{%  for follow in user.following.all %}` etc.